# Arbitrary zsh completion using a keybinding

Tags: zsh

Sometimes a command doesn't have a completion installed—or syntactically could accept a whole bunch of types of arguments, rendering completion next to useless.  For instance, "git checkout" can take the name of any git-tracked file *or* the name of any ref or other tree-ish.  It can also take some option flags.  That's a lot of possible completions.

**Knowing that I want to complete—say—a branch name, is there a way to bind a key to complete against or display a menu of branch names?**  (And likewise for any category of completion.)

That seems possible and useful, but I haven't seen it done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be done.  I originally got the following from one of the zsh mailing lists, but I don't recall who posted it:

```
zle -C complete-file complete-word _generic
zstyle ':completion:complete-file::::' completer _files
bindkey '^x^f' complete-file
```

This could be easily adapted to use a different completion function rather than `_files`.

The first line defines a new completion widget named `complete-file` which behaves like the builtin `complete-word` widget and uses the `_generic` function to generate the list of completions.

The second line then configures it so that when that custom widget is used the completer will only use `_files` to get the list of completions.

Then the third line binds the new widget to a key sequence.